Find the value of the segment $x$ in the figure below
Find the value of the segment $x$ in the figure below. $PN = 17\sqrt2$ (Answer:$11,5$)

I made the figure to scale and found a solution from a colleague using trigonometry, but it would only be possible with a calculator. I believe there must be a geometric solution

$∠PFL=90−(56+17)=17^o$
$∠FPL=180−(45+17)=118^o \implies ∠NPA=45+17=62^o$
$ \therefore LP=PN.cos(62^o)=17\sqrt2.cos(62^o)$
$ \triangle FLP: \frac{LF}{sin(118^o)}=\frac{LP}{sin(17^o)}$
$LF=LP\frac{sin(118^o)}{sin(17^o)}=17\sqrt2.\frac{cos(62^o)sin(118^o)}{sin(17^o)}≈34.08$
$2r=LFsin(56^o)⟹r≈20.55$
$\dfrac{x}{r}=sin(17^o⋅2)⟹x=r.sin(34o)≈\boxed{11.5}$

@CalvinLin My mistake. PN is provided in the statement.

If you carry on the trig functions (instead of computing approximate values) in the end you get a quite simple result: $$x={17\over\sqrt2}\cos17°$$

@Intelligentipauca  That's the problem..there should be a geometric solution..but I didn't find a notable triangle, see x is the mean base of a PRMN trapezoid..and the ex inscribed circle provides many relations but I didn't find one for the measure of x.

Chords subtended by equal angles are equal, hence:
$$
OJ=OL={1\over2}PN={17\over\sqrt2}.
$$
It follows that
$$
x=OQ=OJ\cos17°={17\over\sqrt2}\cos17°\approx 11.5.
$$
